# How can I get suggestedMax number for yAxes?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

How can I get the suggestedMax number for yAxes?
For example, in the image, it is 4000 for legend2 and it is 400 for legend1)

Legend Label 1:

[image: Legend Label 1]

Legend Label 2:

[image: Legend Label 2]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 400],
  }]
};
var option = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: true,
        color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

The problem is the data label goes beyond schedule.

Link to codepen from GitHub : [Link to GitHub discussion](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues/77#issuecomment-410187983)

Comment: do you have access to change the chart.js library or is it third party tool ?

Comment: Downvoted for not accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get the max:

```
// Find the scale in the chart instance
var axis = chartInstance.scales.<scale id>;
var max = axis.max;
var min = axis.min;
```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2444).

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/3820/) for more details.